# TypeError: Cannot read property 'LENGTH_LONG' of undefined

Tags: jestjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am doing jest testing in react native and I have used snackbar in my project. While executing jest i am getting this error.'LENGTH_LONG' is inbuilt variable in snackbar. I am posting where i have used 'LENGTH_LONG' variable and error message. Anyone please help me out

```js
 jest "login"

 FAIL  __tests__\jest\LoginScreen.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'LENGTH_LONG' of undefined

      10 |     ScrollView
      11 | } from "react-native";
    > 12 | import Snackbar from 'react-native-snackbar';
      13 |
      14 | import { connect } from "react-redux";
      15 | import { Button, Text, Divider } from "react-native-elements";

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-snackbar/lib/index.js:1:252)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/screens/login/loginScreen.js:12:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/jest/LoginScreen.test.js:3:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.689s, estimated 4s
Ran all test suites matching /login/i.
```

Code is

```js
render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                {this.renderTopLogoContainer()}
                {this.renderBottomContainer()}

                {this.props.hasError ? Snackbar.show({
                    title: this.props.error.display_message,
                    duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                }) : null}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in android. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/cooperka/react-native-snackbar/tree/master/example
add react-native-snackbar.js file in **mocks** folder

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me. Could you please explain why we should add this file to project?

Answer (score 0):

create a file: 'react-native-snackbar.js' inside the folder '**mocks**' with the code

```
module.exports = {
  show: jest.fn()
};
```

[image: code and file]

Answer (score -2):

You have not mentioned whether you are trying to run in ios or android, recently I've seen this issue in ios because I've missed installing the pod.

**Try this:**

pod install in the ios directory

react-native run-ios

You can also use npm instead of yarn if you prefer.